# Get the time of the next DST change in python

Tags: python, timezone, dst

What would be an easy way to get the time and date of the next time change for a given timezone (in my case US/Eastern) ? I'm hoping there's a better way than iterating over every date until the %Z changes.

Thanks

Comment: Look at [dateutil.tz](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html)

Comment: Looking through that and I don't see anything that would return the next DST change time and date ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an easy way to do that, but since my goal was to schedule a lambda I've actually found a better way. AWS Schedules support the # wildcard to point to a specific instance of a day in a month :

```
cron(0 3 ? 11 1#1 *)
```

This will run at 3am on the first Sunday of November for example, which is what I wanted. Not related to python but just thought I'd share what I ended up going with